# Bitmap Bounding RectF Collision

Tags: android, bitmap, collision-detection, collision

I have been trying to create a simple breakout type game. I have a ball and a bat and want to invert the ball's direction when it collides with the bat. The bat is controlled by the user's touch and can freely move around the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = (int) event.getX();
    y = (int) event.getY();
    return true;
}
```

---

In my game loop:

```
    int cx = -1;
    int cy = -1;

    private int xVelocity = -11;
    private int yVelocity = -14;

    Bitmap player, ball;
    RectF boundsPlayer, boundsBall;

    float boundCX, boundCY;
```

---

```
    boundCX = (float) cx;
    boundCY = (float) cy;
    player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nightplayer);
    canvas.drawBitmap(player, x - (player.getWidth() / 2), y - (player.getHeight() + 100), null);

    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

    boundsPlayer = new RectF((x - (player.getWidth()/2)), (y - (player.getHeight() + 150)), ((x - (player.getWidth()/2)) + player.getWidth()), ((y - (player.getHeight() + 150)) + player.getHeight()));
    boundsBall = new RectF(boundCX, boundCY, boundCX + ball.getWidth(), boundCY + ball.getHeight());

    if (RectF.intersects(boundsBall, boundsPlayer)) {
                       collision();
    }

private void collision() {
        yVelocity = yVelocity * -1;
        score = score + 1;
        //Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(score));
        yVelocity = yVelocity - 2;
        if(xVelocity < 0) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity - 2;
        } else if (xVelocity > 0) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity + 2;
        }
        collision = false;
    }
```

The issue I am having is that when the ball collides with the bat it seems to collide multiple times and repeatedly inverts the direction instead of "bouncing off" of the bat.

Comment: I don't see you checking for the direction in which the ball is moving, perhaps that's the cause, since during the moment of collision, the collision method my be executed several times.

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: Then update your solution as the answer.